# Convert abc pqrs xyz on separate lines into 'abc','pqrs','xyz' on a single line, using awk

Tags: awk, text-formatting

```
printf 'abc\npqrs\nxyz\n' | awk $'{ print "\'" $0 "\'" ,sep="," ,ORS=""}'
```

Output: `'abc' , 'pqrs' , 'xyz' ,`

expected output: remove last/ end of the comma(,) and remove spaces.

Comment: please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk and only storing one line of input at a time in memory:

```
$ printf 'abc\npqrs\nxyz\n' |
    awk '{printf "%s\047%s\047", sep, $0; sep=","} END{print ""}'
'abc','pqrs','xyz'
```

The above will continue to work even if an input line was empty:

```
$ printf 'abc\n\npqrs\nxyz\n' |
    awk '{printf "%s\047%s\047", sep, $0; sep=","} END{print ""}'
'abc','','pqrs','xyz'
```

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes that you want a properly quoted CSV row that takes into account that you may have embedded single quotes or commas in the data:

```bash
csvformat -d $'\n' -Q "'" -U1 | paste -d, -s -
```

It uses the CSV-aware tool `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to format the data appropriately, with single quotes as the quoting character, quoting all fields, even those that do not need quoting (remove `-U1` to only quote fields that need quoting). The lines are read as single newline-delimited fields.

The `paste` utility is then used to reshape the data into a single line with commas in-between the fields.

Testing:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' "It's the first" "The middle" "And, the last" | csvformat -d $'\n' -Q "'" -U1 | paste -d, -s -
'It''s the first','The middle','And, the last'
```

Answer (score 1):

For sufficiently small input such that it doesn't overflow `xargs`' buffer, here's a non-`awk` suggestion:

```
printf 'abc\npqrs\nxyz\n' | xargs | sed -e "s/ /','/g" -e "s/\(.*\)/'\1'/"
```

Output

```
'abc','pqrs','xyz'
```

And here's an obligatory `awk` version

```
printf 'abc\npqrs\nxyz\n' |
    awk "END {printf \"'\\n\"} NR==1 {printf \"'%s\", \$0} NR>1 {printf \"','%s\", \$0}"
```

Output

```
'abc','pqrs','xyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution using awk:

```
$ printf 'abc\npqrs\nxyz\n' | 
  awk 'BEGIN{q="\047"}  { printf c q "%s" q , $0 ; c=","}END{print "" }'

'abc','pqrs','xyz'
```